# Stop image from being downloaded when on a smartphone

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, smartphone

I'm developing a responsive website for a company where the full size website has a slideshow with images in the background (filling the screen completely with Backstretch). Since the images are pretty hefty in size (around 300k), I'm looking for a way to stop the images from being loaded when viewing the site on a smartphone.

I've applied `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` on the backstretch div with a media query. It hides the images, but it seems like they are still being downloaded. Is there a smart way to make the browser ignore them altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're setting the image through CSS then there is a way.

If you set the div to display:none it will still download, however if you set the parent div to display none then it will not load until a media query fires to set

**CSS**

```
.parent {display:block;}
.background {background-image:url(myimage.png);}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
.parent {display:none;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Hat tip to Tim Kadlec - http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: This still loads the images.Correct?

Comment: @praaveen only once the media query fires (because the parent element of the image container has been set to not display)

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to go the mobile-first approach, defining the default styles for mobile and overriding these in media queries for larger screen widths.

Something like the following will prevent the image being downloaded on a mobile device, and also avoids the need for an unnecessary wrapper div :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- slideshow container -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* default to no background image */
.container {
    background-image: none; 
}

/* add it in for wider screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .container {
        background-image: url(myimage.png);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`visibility` and `display` have nothing to do with whether an image is downloaded. The only thing you can do is have all images as background-images and use a media query to exclude them completely in your alternate stylesheet.

Comment: The Backstretch jQuery plugin I use to display the background images put the images in a div right above the closing body tag. I tried using background-size to scale the background, but that is a power hog on Google Chrome (and is not supported in older browsers). I've uploaded the page [here](http://www.andersnoren.se/private/272/uppdrag/rbj/). Is there a way to do this without removing Backstretch?